# Passing bools from one class to another using a dto

Tags: c#, .net, dto

```cs
public void GetUserPermission(string username)
{
    using var db = new SOSContext();
    {
        var userAccount = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserName == username);
        UserPermissionsDTO userPermissions = new UserPermissionsDTO()
        {
            CanManageUsers = userAccount.CanManageUsers,
            CanManageCustomers = userAccount.CanManageCustomers,
            CanManageStocks = userAccount.CanManageStocks,
            CanManageOrders = userAccount.CanManageOrders,
            CanManageDeliveries = userAccount.CanManageDeliveries,
        };
    }
```

I have this method which queries a database to check the user permissions for the user that matches the correct username. I am trying to transfer these userpermissions to the login.xaml.cs class in my application. I am using a dto object to do this.

```cs
class UserPermissionsDTO
{
    public bool CanManageUsers { get; set; }
    public bool CanManageCustomers { get; set; }
    public bool CanManageStocks { get; set; }
    public bool CanManageOrders { get; set; }
    public bool CanManageDeliveries { get; set; }
}
```

The problem I have when the instance of the dto object is created in the userpermissions method if the userpermissions values are true this value is not transferred to my login.xaml.cs. When I debug the program the value of all the userpermissions DTO is set to the default value of false. Does anyone have any suggestions of a better way to transfer user permissions or fix this broken code?

[using QuickWatch to check value of userpermissions dto variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hs9yT.jpg)

Comment: I guess you'll have to show us how you transfer your `userPermissions` object to your view.

Comment: Try changing the return type of `GetUserPermission` from `void` to `UserPermissionsDTO`.  Then in your calling code (from your screenshot) change to `UserPermissionsDTO userPermissions = GetUserPermission(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Your `GetUserPermission` is of type `void` so it is not returning any information to the caller. it should return `UserPermissionsDTO` instead. After you created your `userPermissions` dto, return it from the call and make the caller use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your dto first and pass it to GetUserPermission method and assign your values there. Then you can use those values from where you called the method. Something like this should work:

```
public void GetUserPermission(string username, UserPermissionsDTO dto)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username)) return;

        using var db = new SOSContext();
        {
            var userAccount = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserName.ToLower() == username.ToLower());
            if (userAccount == null) return;
            dto.CanManageUsers = userAccount.CanManageUsers;
            dto.CanManageCustomers = userAccount.CanManageCustomers;
            dto.CanManageStocks = userAccount.CanManageStocks;
            dto.CanManageOrders = userAccount.CanManageOrders;
            dto.CanManageDeliveries = userAccount.CanManageDeliveries;
        }
    }
```

To call the above method:

```
var userPermissions = new UserPermissionsDTO();
userService.GetUserPermission(username, userPermissions);
var canManagerUsers = userPermissions.CanManageUsers;
// Map other permissions
```

Comment: I call the GetUserPermissions method in my login.xaml.cs class but I don't see why before defining the userpermissions dto I would want to check if the username is null or empty because I have another method called userlogin which has already done this before the user permissions code is executed